# How to refresh ListView so that the selected item becomes fully visible when a footer appears and overlaps it?

Tags: android

I have a `ListView` with a few checkboxes and a footer that I have to show when one of these checkboxes is checked.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if I click on an item that would be overlapped by this footer, the `ListView` would scroll automatically to show this item. Note that the `ListView` is laid correctly and can be further scrolled.

I've tried this in the onItemClicked function and it hasn't worked so far:

```
if (mFooterView.getVisibility() != View.VISIBLE) {
    mFooterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    mImagesListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
}
```

The problem seems to be that smoothScrollToPosition uses the current measurement, which gets invalidated by `mFooterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)`. The new measurements, however, don't seem to be available until the next redraw.

Is there anyway I can achieve this effect? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the `ListView`'s source code for a while I managed to solve this by taking some inspiration from `ListView.onSizeChanged()`. The key was to do the scrolling after the ListView was actually resized. We can do this by using the `post` function.

Here's the code (note that it doesn't scroll, just sets the correct position, but you get the idea):

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

    if (mFooterView.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
        mFooterView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // at this point, the listview's height hasn't changed yet
        int listOldHeight = parent.getHeight();

        if (mItemAutoVisibilityScroller == null) {
            mItemAutoVisibilityScroller = new ItemAutoVisibilityScroller();
        }

        // allow the list to resize
        mFooterView.post(mItemAutoVisibilityScroller.setup(listOldHeight, position, view.getTop(), view.getHeight()));
    } else {
        mFooterView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

private class ItemAutoVisibilityScroller implements Runnable {
    private int mListOldHeight;
    private int mPosition;
    private int mItemTop;
    private int mItemHeight;

    public ItemAutoVisibilityScroller setup(int listOldHeight, int position, int itemTop, int itemHeight) {
        mListOldHeight = listOldHeight;
        mPosition = position;
        mItemTop = itemTop;
        mItemHeight = itemHeight;
        return this;
    }

    public void run() {
        final int textTop = mFooterView.getTop();

        // is the item cut by the footer?
        if (mItemTop + mItemHeight > textTop) {

            int newItemTop = mListOldHeight - mFooterView.getHeight() - mItemHeight;
            if (newItemTop < 0) {
                newItemTop = 0;
            }

            // move the item just above the footer
            mListView.setSelectionFromTop(mPosition, newItemTop);
        }
    }
}
```